# Efficient way to handle COM related errors (C++)

Tags: c++, com

Efficient way to handle COM related errors in **C++**.

For instance:

```
 switch (HRESULT_CODE(hresult)) {
    case NOERROR:
                cout << "Object instantiated and "
                "pointer to interface IS8Simulation " 
                "obtained" << endl;
        break;
    //Specifed Class not registered
    case REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG:
        cerr << "Specified Class not registered." << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    case CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION:
                cerr << "The Class does not support aggregation "
                "(or class object is remote)." << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    //Interface not supported - exit with error
    case E_NOINTERFACE:
        cerr << "No such interface supported." << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    case E_UNEXPECTED:
    default:
        cerr << "Catastrophic failure." << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
 }
```

Compared to, the **former**:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hresult))
{
            cout << "The COM library was initialised"
            " successfully on this thread" << endl;
} else {
            cerr << "Fatal Error: COM library was not"
            " initialised" << endl;
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Question:

- Any other method more applicable?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351.aspx) to get the error text -- it already knows how to look up the localized text for most HRESULTs and Win32 result codes.

Use the `FAILED` and `SUCCEEDED` macros to work out if something has worked or not.

`exit` takes 32-bit numbers. You can use an HRESULT as your process exit code:

```
HRESULT hr;
if (FAILED(hr = p->QueryInterface(...)))
{
    cerr << MessageFromHResult(hr); // left as an exercise for the reader
    exit(hr);
}
```